# Which method should I use for a "complex" UPDATE statement?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to execute a statement such as

```
UPDATE myTable SET myField = myField + 1
```

in an Android SQLite database. (Yes, I want to increment myField for all records.)

My first idea was to use [`execSQL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29), but the documentation says:

> execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.
>
> ...
>
> For UPDATE statements, use any of the following instead.
>   • update(String, ContentValues, String, String[])
>   • updateWithOnConflict(String, ContentValues, String, String[], int)

However, as far as I can see, this type of UPDATE cannot be done with the [`SQLiteDatabase.update` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29). Did I miss some clever trick to do this with `SQLiteDatabase.update` or is the documentation broken? (Running the above SQL with execSQL works fine, although the documentation claims otherwise.)

Comment: My understanding of this is to read "that is NOT" as "should NOT be" since there are dedicated methods form the others.

Comment: @Simon: The problem is that it really must not be used for `select`. And `pragma` that returns value for that matter, because this method has no way to return the value and won't step the statement until all results were yielded. But it is just fine for any statement that does not return values including `insert/update/delete`. They have helper methods, but at for some SQL like that I regularly work with (which I acknowledge is not on Android and is not typical Android use-case) they are not appropriate. They are not appropriate for the SQL in question either.

Comment: Agreed,  My comment was more around the docs which could be better (isn't that the case for most of Android?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That method is just fine. It has to be, because the underlying C API does not distinguish those. Any statement that does not return value can be executed with `execSQL`.

The `update`* and `insert`* are legitimate helper methods, but the documentation would really do better if it didn't claim they must be used for all inserts/updates since they simply can't be (ever used `insert into table select ...`? I do that all the time!)

Answer (score 1):

The `execSQL` will work fine in this case because it returns nothing. I am using it for the same purpose in one of my application and i never experinced issues.